# How to compare username password and secret code with text file to login java

Tags: java

Below my code is only to input data into text file now i have to make a new login form when user put username password and secret code it will logged in if wrong then error i put some data in text file using code below now i want to compare from text file and logged in i am making a java program on sublime i am newbie this is my assignment how to compare in simplest way with text file data, text file contains username password secret code in same line how to arrange that i am stuck i am trying from last 9 hours its assignment

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class Reg{

    public static void main (String[]args)throws IOException {

        Users p = new Users();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter username");
        String uu = sc.nextLine();
        p.setUser(uu);
        System.out.println("Enter password");
        String pp = sc.nextLine();
        p.setPassword(pp);
        System.out.println("Enter Secret number");
        String ss = sc.nextLine();
        p.setSecret(ss);

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true));
        pw.write(uu);
        pw.write(pp);
        pw.write(ss);


    pw.close();

}
}
```

Comment: This is the most insecure way to handle logging in. However, just use a file reader and read in the first line as the username, the second line as the password, and the third line as the secret. Compare to the values inputted.

Comment: Its just a assignment for understanding of logic that's why i am using text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already created the pw, don't need to create again and i write something in the code you read from it. I wish it will help you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Reg{

        public static void main (String[]args)throws IOException {

            Users p = new Users();
            String uu = "";
            String pp = "";
            String ss = "";
            //I think you created a method in Users and say logined or something error.
            While(Users.getLogin == false){
            //***I don't know the Users class you made

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter username");
            uu = sc.nextLine();
            p.setUser(uu);
            System.out.println("Enter password");
            pp = sc.nextLine();
            p.setPassword(pp);
            System.out.println("Enter Secret number");
            ss= sc.nextLine();
            p.setSecret(ss);

            }



            //Something like this
        if(Users.getLogin == true){
            //if you wanna write something to the file, u can use this.
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            pw.write(uu);
            pw.write(pp);
            pw.write(ss);

            //if you wanna write line by line use writeln, not write.


        pw.close();

    }
        }
}
```

Comment: Now if i want to login from other java program what i have to do, its a registration form

Comment: I think you firstly try to learn java and then socket/io or something else to communicate between clients and server. Because no one can teach you what you have to learn and can't educate you. This platform mostly for the share our problems in the code.

Comment: @RazaKhan **[Post a new question if you have a new question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “russian doll questions” are not quite welcome")** Do not use followup comments to ask new questions if the original question was already solved.